# Unable to reproduce data from Azure Metrics Chart using Logs

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-dashboard

I am trying to create dashboard of my services in Azure. I added Azure Metrics Chart of each service and later wanted to add under it specific details to operations included in service.

[image]

But when I try to get it from logs, I get much higher number of requests made. KQL:

```
requests
| where cloud_RoleName startswith "notificationengine"
| summarize Count = count() by operation_Name
| order by Count
```

And result:

[image]

Problem is with some metrics chart I get values with minimal difference or exactly same while with some like one I shown I get completely different values. I tried to modify KQL or search what might be wrong but never got anywhere.

My guess is that those are 2 different values but in that case why both are labeled as "requests" and if so what are actual differences?

Answer (score 0):

*I have taken an Azure Function App with 2 Http Trigger Functions with identical names starts with “HttpTrigger” and run both the functions for couple of times.*

**Test Case 1:**

In the Logs Workspace, Requests count got for the two functions that starts with the word “`HttpTrigger`”:

[image]

But I have pinned the chart of only 1 Function Requests Count to the Azure Dashboard:

[image]

Probably, I believe you have written the query of requests of all the services/applications that starts with “`notificationengine`” but pinned only some apps/services logs-chart to the dashboard.

**Test Case 2:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: so if I understand correctly those metric charts don't show all requests made even though I can select only scope as whole? Because for example I have another service where if I go with kql:`requests
| where cloud_RoleName == "parking-core01"
` I get high number of requests made in selected time span but metrics chart shows me 0.

Comment: scope is something on which resource level you need the logs but you have to add the query as metric chart to dashboard and in the query you already mentioned need the metrics for all the cloud roles that starts with some keyword.